# Переключить буфер без движения экрана

Tags: vim

Допустим, есть два файла, первый выглядит как-то так (как выглядит второй неважно):

```
001 #include <stdio.h>
002
003 int main(void)
004 {
005     puts("hello world");
006     return 0;
007 }
```

При этом, высота терминала, например, три строки. Я перемещаю курсор на третью строку и делаю `zt`. В терминале получаю:

```
003 int main(void)
004 {
005     puts("hello world");
```

Всё отлично. Но после перемещения на второй файл командой `:bnext` и возвращения через `:bprev`, экран смещается так, что строка с курсором становится посередине. То есть, в терминале я получаю:

```
002 
003 int main(void)
004 {
```

**Вопрос:** Как перемещаться между буферами, не трогая положение экрана относительно курсора?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для решения можно воспользоваться следующим способом:

1. Прежде чем перейти в другой buffer, сохраняем текущие настройки окна.
2. Как только переходим (возвращаемся) в buffer, восстанавливаем ранее сохранённые для него настройки.

Готовое решение находим здесь https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Avoid_scrolling_when_switch_buffers и добавляем его в ~/.vimrc:

```
" Save current view settings on a per-window, per-buffer basis.
function! AutoSaveWinView()
    if !exists("w:SavedBufView")
        let w:SavedBufView = {}
    endif
    let w:SavedBufView[bufnr("%")] = winsaveview()
endfunction

" Restore current view settings.
function! AutoRestoreWinView()
    let buf = bufnr("%")
    if exists("w:SavedBufView") && has_key(w:SavedBufView, buf)
        let v = winsaveview()
        let atStartOfFile = v.lnum == 1 && v.col == 0
        if atStartOfFile && !&diff
            call winrestview(w:SavedBufView[buf])
        endif
        unlet w:SavedBufView[buf]
    endif
endfunction

" When switching buffers, preserve window view.
if v:version >= 700
    autocmd BufLeave * call AutoSaveWinView()
    autocmd BufEnter * call AutoRestoreWinView()
endif
```